# How avoid horizontal html scrolling when a layer is show

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div `.layer` that darkens the entire page to highlight a modal, but when I trigger the event there is a problem to occupying 100% of the screen, and is that the scroll bar of the original browser is deleted

Is there any fancy way to make the div `.layer`, when is visible, keep the original bar scroll of the page?

In smartphones / tablet I do not find any problem when shooting the event `.layer").show();` **but on desktop screens the original scroll bar of browser is eliminated and the whole html document moves to right, taking its place.**

What would be the correct way to avoid html to the right?

Thanks in advance!

**HTML:**

```
<div class="layer"></div>
<div class="open-modal">Open</div>

<div class="modal">
  <div class="close-modal">Close</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {width:100%;min-height:100%;margin:0 auto;top:0;left:0;padding:0}
body {top:0;left:0;margin:0;padding:0;min-height:100%}

.layer {
display:none;
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
min-height:100vh;
background:rgba(0,0,0,.9);
z-index:2
}

.modal {display:none;z-index:1}
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".open-modal").click(function(){
    $(".modal,.layer").show();
    $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
  });
    $(".close-modal,.layer").click(function(){
      $(".close-modal,.layer").hide();
      $("body").css("overflow","");
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not remove $("body").css("overflow","hidden") and $("body").css("overflow","")?

Comment: @Arye Eidelman Thanks. I will take note of this error in my script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of your use of "overflow".  I've included a link below to the Mozilla Developer Network docs for "overflow", but below is a quick quote explaining what's happening.

"hidden
Content is clipped if necessary to fit the padding box. **No scrollbars are provided**, and **no support for allowing the user to scroll (such as by dragging or using a scroll wheel) is allowed**. The content can be scrolled programmatically (for example, by setting the value of a property such as offsetLeft), so the element is still a scroll container."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Also, after one cycle of clicking Open and Close, if you were to click Open again, the word Close won't show up.  That's because you're not using the .show() method to show that text upon clicking Open.  Updated JavaScript below.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".open-modal").click(function(){
    $(".modal,.layer,.close-modal").show();
  });
    $(".close-modal,.layer").click(function(){
      $(".close-modal,.layer").hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will take note of this error in my script

Comment: Glad I could help.